# Unable to use TabLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

If you have faced this and resolved help.

Unable to use  TabLayoutManager, I think it has got to do with version of material design and viewpager2, I have used the latest versions for both of them.

versions.material="1.3.0-alpha02"
versions.material="1.3.0-alpha02"

```
versions.material="1.3.0-alpha02"
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

[image]

Using like this,

[image]

Comment: You should try update your material design version to the latest : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases

Comment: @Biscuit actually i am useing the latest versions already.
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=material#com.google.android.material:material

have checked in the following website.
which is : 1.3.0-alpha02

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've implemented my ViewPager2/TabLayout

Try a Clean/Rebuild if that's not working then try File > Invalidate cache and Restart

I only used this implementation:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
```

**My XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Fragment**

```kotlin
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding.viewPager.adapter =
    ViewPagerAdapter(it.data, childFragmentManager, viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.myTablayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = tabTitle(it.data[position])
     }.attach()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Biscuit
bro ,
 tabLayoutMediator is not supported because of some internal bug, saw in a google forum.
Tried to used not alpha version of these library, was facing other issues, so reverted back to latest alpha version.